# AWS EC2 Container Service Container Id, what does this mean?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2

I have a EC2 Container Service running a task which requires two docker containers.  The task is running fine and I can see the two containers.[Please refer to the attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdQFS.png).  My problem is that when I rdp into the EC2 instance running the images and try **docker images** sure enough I see two containers, but their **CONTAINER ID** is different from what is shown on the web page.  Can someone shed some light on this please.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I assume you are trying to get the docker container ID?

Comment: The container id in aws console is not same as containerid retrieved by loggin in ec2 instance

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for something similar.
In the image you point to both the **Container ID**s and the **Container Instance**.
These are two separate things. 
A **Container Instance** is used by the ECS-Agent for monitoring the containers within the ECS instance.
An **AWS Container ID** is used by AWS in place of the **Docker Container ID** (Which they refer to as the "**Docker ID**"). 
AWS refer to the **AWS Container ID** as **Container ID**.
The Container ID you see when you RDP or SSH into an instance is the **Docker Container ID**.

If you want to correlate between the two container IDs you need to use the task ARN (Appears at the top of the image). You need to log into the instance hosting the containers, and from it's terminal `curl http://localhost:51678/v1/tasks`.

You will get something similar to:

`{
  "Tasks": [
    {
      "Arn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:<aws_account_id>:task/example5-58ff-46c9-ae05-543f8example",
      "DesiredStatus": "RUNNING",
      "KnownStatus": "RUNNING",
      "Family": "hello_world",
      "Version": "8",
      "Containers": [
        {
          "DockerId": "9581a69a761a557fbfce1d0f6745e4af5b9dbfb86b6b2c5c4df156f1a5932ff1",
          "DockerName": "ecs-hello_world-8-mysql-fcae8ac8f9f1d89d8301",
          "Name": "mysql"
        },
        {
          "DockerId": "bf25c5c5b2d4dba68846c7236e75b6915e1e778d31611e3c6a06831e39814a15",
          "DockerName": "ecs-hello_world-8-wordpress-e8bfddf9b488dff36c00",
          "Name": "wordpress"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}`

This is based on: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-introspection.html

According to AWS support there is not way to currently do this without logging into the instance.